# Can emulator in android studio shares full screen with other application in MAC?

Tags: macos, android-studio, emulation

I notice when I try to move emulator to another full-screened application, it was disabled. Is there any way to make it share screen? I am using android studio 2.3.3. It should be a useful property when using a 21:9 screen...